# SQL Query with single quotes

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

getting Error while executing this query , because column text may contain text with single quotes also. How can i use this query w/o any error
My code is

```
public bool updateCMStable(int id, string columnName, string columnText)
{
    try
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE  CMStable SET " + columnName + 
                      "='" + columnText + "' WHERE cmsID=" + id;
        int i = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection.ConnectionString,
                                          CommandType.Text,
                                          sql);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        throw ee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are getting in this code.

Comment: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: So you realise the try/catch here does nothing useful, but does some bad things? Escaping things is **not** the right fix here: this should 100% use parameterisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your code, escape all single quotes with an additional single quote.  **However I agree with Oded... you need to be using a parameterized query, or possibly a stored proc.**

```
public bool updateCMStable(int id, string columnName, string columnText) 
{ 
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty))
   {
       switch(columnName)
       {
           // TODO: change 50 & 100 to the real sizes of your columns, 
           // and obviously the column names too...
           case "column1":
               if(columnText.Length > 50)
                   columnText = columnText.SubString(0, 50);
               break;
           case "column2":
               if(columnText.Length > 100)
                   columnText = columnText.SubString(0, 100);
               break;
           etc... 
        }
    }
    // replace single quote with double single quotes
    columnText = columnText.Replace("'", "''");
    string sql = string.Format("UPDATE CMStable SET {0} = '{1}' WHERE cmsID={2}", 
        columnName, 
        columnText, 
        id); 
    int i = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection.ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, sql); 
    return (i > 0); 
}
```

I made some additional corrections to your code.

1. You can simply return the result of an if statement when you're returning true | false
2. You don't need to catch exceptions if you're simply going to throw it in the catch block
3. If you DO catch an exception, do something meaningful with it, and decide to rethrow it, use `throw` by itself, or you'll reset the stack trace.  Don't use `throw ee`;
4. Replace + type concatination with string.Format if it becomes too unreadable.

**Edit:**

The error you posted is happening because the length of the data being passed in is longer than the specified length of the column.  Since you're using dynamic SQL, the only way around it that I can see is to use a case statement.  Each field may have a different size, or maybe not, but the string will have to be truncated to fit to avoid the error.  If all the field sizes are the same, you won't need the case statement.

Comment: @user1372444 Concatenating strings to form SQL is plain wrong, as warned at the top of this answer. Don't become another mug who implemented a security vuln.

Comment: @spender - and I believe with a param type query, the double single quote thing can be removed as well, because I think it's handled automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of constructing your SQL in a string you should use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) - your current code, apart from having an issue with single quotes is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

There is a limitation in that you are trying to use a dynamic column name which cannot be parameterized, but you can still use dynamic SQL in a safer manner.

I suggest reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog for a comprehensive treatment of the subject.

Comment: +1 for parameterized queries - using SQL in code instead of stored procs is not only going to make it less maintainable, but is also asking for sql injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error was

***"String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated"***

Main cause of this error is the shorter length of the column in which you are trying to save any value, suppose if your column is of `varchar(100)` type and you try to save a string of 105 characters in it then you'll get this error.

Comment: i have nvarchar(max) datatype for my column

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinqToSql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx).  Please.......  there are lots of reasons why writing code as you've listed above is not a good idea - security, design, sanity....

Google LinqToSql and "Repository Pattern" as a basic starting point for writing maintainable, useful data interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public bool updateCMStable(int id, string columnName, string columnText)
{
    try
    {
        columnText=columnText.Replace("'","''")
        string sql = "UPDATE  CMStable SET " + columnName + 
                      "='" + columnText + "' WHERE cmsID=" + id;
        int i = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection.ConnectionString,
                                          CommandType.Text,
                                          sql);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        throw ee;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool updateCMStable(int id, string columnName, string columnText)
            {
                 try
                {
string sql = "UPDATE  CMStable SET '"+columnName+"' = '"+columnText+"' where cmdID='"+id+"'";
int i = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection.ConnectionString,CommandType.Text,sql);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        throw ee;
    }
}
```